# Can you update/insert/delete via MongoDB ODBC driver?

Tags: mongodb, odbc

I'm looking to migrate a system that uses an ODBC driver to talk to MySQL and change it to talk to MongoDB. By using mongosqld, BI Connector and a DRDL schema I can access the data and my "select * from ..." queries all work fine. However, I keep getting an error when I try to UPDATE the data. Is this a limitation of the driver or am I doing something wrong?

The error I get is:

[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.12 mongosqld v2.14.0]parse sql 'update `User` set name='Simon Sawyer' where `userid`='3ecdf4a51478644780782b20'' error: unexpected UPDATE at position 8 near update

Comment: Which ODBC driver do you use?

Comment: It was the free one from MongoDB. In the end I played around with wrapping the .net library in a COM component so my Classic ASP could make calls to MongoDB... not ideal but worked!